# I have the following array, coming from a form

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => rubix ) 
Array ( [0] => limo )
Array ( [0] => icecream )
```

I need to convert this array into following type. How can I do that? For example like this:

```
 Array ( [0] => rubix [1] => schoolbag [3] => limo [4] => frezzer [5] => paper )
```

Comment: Please give some more information. Your question is not clear.

Comment: where did the elements 'schoolbag' & 'frezzer' come from?

Comment: Loop through the mother array and newarray.push(array[count][0])

Comment: Array ( [0] => rubix )

Array ( [0] => limo )

Array ( [0] => icecream ) coming from database

Comment: are these separate array just like you've given or multidimensional array like Array([0]=>Array([0]=>rubix) [1]=>Array([0]=>limo))....

Comment: Array ( [0] => rubix ) 
Array ( [0] => limo )
Array ( [0] => icecream )  this format coming from database  and i need to convert into   Array ( [0] => rubix [1] => schoolbag [3] => limo [4] => frezzer [5] => paper ) bcz i want to use array_diff($a1,$a2);

Comment: plz give some information about this

Answer (score 0):

[array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is an option if you want to combine arrays.

```
$array1 = array("id1" => "rubix ");

$array2 = array("id2" => "limo ", "id3" => "icecream ", "id4" => "frezzer ");

$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2/*, $arrayN, $arrayN*/);
```